# Syntax error in sqlite statement in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following code fragment in an object initializer. However, the third line below gives the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

```
self._conn = sqlite3.connect('dictionary')
cursor = self._conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE `words` (`word` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY (`word`));')
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this. I'm far from an export at SQL but I fail to see what I did incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `KEY` here.

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (`word` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`word`))
```

Answer (score 0):

`PRIMARY word` is not valid SQL. Use

```
CREATE TABLE words (word VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```